# Incorrect INSERT in procedure with function now()

Tags: mysql, function, insert, procedure, concatenation

I think proble is with char example " or ' in query CONCAT (INSERT....) I always get error:

> 0 16:35:45    call
>   InsertUser(990099,2,1,"Title1","Gosc","aaa","192.168.1.1",21426,23453245,1)   Error
>   Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near '16:35:44, 1, 1)' at line 2

to procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS InsertUser $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `InsertUser`
      (UserId int, ServiceId int(11), CommentsId int(11), 
       Title varchar(255), Nick varchar(20), content text,
       Ip varchar(15), TableCrc int(5),Crc32 int(11) unsigned,
       ArticleId int(11))
BEGIN

        DECLARE tableName VARCHAR(65535);

        set tableName = CONCAT('User',userId);

        CALL CreateUsersTable(tableName);


        set @a = CONCAT("INSERT INTO `", tableName ,"` (`ServiceId`,   
                               `CommentsId`, `Title`, `Content`,`Ip`,
                               `TableCrc`, `Crc32`, `ArticleId`,`Date`,
                                `ViewStatus`, `CommentStatus`) 
                         VALUES (",ServiceId,", ",CommentsId,", '",Title,"',
                                 '",Content,"', '",Ip,"', ",TableCrc,", 
                                ",Crc32,", ",ArticleId,", 
                             ",now(),", 1, 1);");

        PREPARE stmi FROM @a;
        EXECUTE stmi;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmi;          

END$$
```

Comment: have you tried  to put quotes around the now() statement? `'",now(),"', 1, 1);");`

Comment: yes I true but it doesnt work

Comment: ITS NOW OK Problem is with parametr in entry.

Comment: Hi Przemek, welcome to StackOverflow! Glad you could solve your problem. Now you should answer your own question and check it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an embedded space in the string value returned by NOW()

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
          ^
```

In your SQL statement, that needs to be treated as a string, which means it needs to be enclosed in single quotes. As a separate issue, you do not need a semicolon as part of your SQL text:

change this:

```
", ",now(),", 1, 1);");
                   ^
```

to this:

```
", '",now(),"', 1, 1)");
   ^         ^
```